# JSEncrypt(js) encrypt, but python cannot decrypt

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, encryption

I'm trying RSA encrypt text with JSEncrypt(javascript) and decrypt with python crypto (python3.7). Most of the time, it works. But sometimes, python cannot decrypt.

```js
const encrypt = new JSEncrypt()
encrypt.setPublicKey(publicKey)
encrypt.encrypt(data)
```

```py
from base64 import b64decode
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5 as Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

crypt_text = "J9I/IdsSGZqrQ5XBTlDrze5+U3otrGEGn7J7f330/tbIpdPNwu9k5gCh35HJHuRF6tXhbOD9XbHS6dGXwRdj0KNSWa43tDQMyGp/ZSewCd4wWkqIx83YzDKnYTVc9zWYbg2iYrmR03AqtWMysl8vZDUSmQn7gNdYEJGxSUzVng=="
private_key = "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"

decode_data = b64decode(crypt_text)
other_private_key = RSA.importKey(b64decode(private_key))
cipher = Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5.new(other_private_key)
decrypt_text = cipher.decrypt(decode_data, None).decode()
print(decrypt_text)
```

this is a example text that python can't decrypt, but js can decrypt it well.
python throws the error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_v1_5.py", line 165, in decrypt
    raise ValueError("Ciphertext with incorrect length.")
ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length.
```

Comment: Your `crypt_text` has two base64 encoded outputs concatenated together.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited crypt_text. Could you give some suggestions?@JamesKPolk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ciphertext is Base64-decoded, the reason becomes clearer: The ciphertext doesn't have the length of the modulus (128 byte), but only 127 byte, i.e. it isn't padded to the length of the modulus with leading `0x00` values. This ciphertext is invalid (see [RFC8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-7.2.2), step 1) and the decryption in the Python code fails with the error message *Ciphertext with incorrect length*. In contrast, the decryption in the JavaScript code works, i.e. `JSEncrypt#decrypt` obviously adjusts the ciphertext to the length of the modulus by stealthily padding with `0x00` values. If the ciphertext was created with `JSEncrypt#encrypt`, this method doesn't seem to work properly.

In detail: The modulus can be determined with:

```
openssl rsa -modulus -noout -in <path to private key>
```

and is (as hex-string):

```
A51489A0ECDFB9CE21AD8EB303C0DEDFAE8A2D830ACB5266C4F58141B5E7278DC842463027D70AAAEBD5E25B29C4BF4AB7FD4F753798349C9C5E32EA2548CF1CC1D41B4F7299170405EAFADE4B30CD85F1183AC1556649C82CB3E22695189B9C371A2DF851E33AD221C61FD1149E641E5702921B4585DA72B648253A1327E827
```

The length is 128 byte. The Base64-decoded ciphertext is (as hex-string):

```
27d23f21db12199aab4395c14e50ebcdee7e537a2dac61069fb27b7f7df4fed6c8a5d3cdc2ef64e600a1df91c91ee445ead5e16ce0fd5db1d2e9d197c11763d0a35259ae37b4340cc86a7f6527b009de305a4a88c7cdd8cc32a761355cf735986e0da262b991d3702ab56332b25f2f6435129909fb80d7581091b1494cd59e
```

The length is 127 byte. If the ciphertext is padded manually to the length of the modulus with `0x00`-values, it can also be decrypted in the Python code:

```
0027d23f21db12199aab4395c14e50ebcdee7e537a2dac61069fb27b7f7df4fed6c8a5d3cdc2ef64e600a1df91c91ee445ead5e16ce0fd5db1d2e9d197c11763d0a35259ae37b4340cc86a7f6527b009de305a4a88c7cdd8cc32a761355cf735986e0da262b991d3702ab56332b25f2f6435129909fb80d7581091b1494cd59e
```

The decrypted data are:

```
Mzg4MDE1NDU4MTI1ODI0OA==NDQyODYwNjI1MjU4NTM2MA==
```

which are two valid Base64-encoded strings.

Comment: Your answer is fantastic！It works with padding '00' to the ciphertext. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That sounds like a bug in JSencrypt. Maybe file a bug report?

Comment: @JamesKPolk - I've filed an issue [here](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt/issues/158).

Comment: @Topaco, you are great!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Topaco, it solved.

```
from base64 import b64decode, b16decode
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5 as Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

crypt_text = \
    "R247QGAFEeSW1wwXQuNf/cm/K/tnW5xwXLb5MuHW6/Fr8SRklM0n6Rmj07TgFwApeN72j/avXAvpoR70U92ehOJsDnnZguYN4u2bMXHDyTNmAXuJw9xPm59bSGcvgRm1X+V0Zq1FLzGEsPG6tOYEIX+wnIuH3P7QMd02XJfj0w0="
private_key = "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"

decode_data = b64decode(crypt_text)
if len(decode_data) == 127:
    hex_fixed = '00' + decode_data.hex()
    decode_data = b16decode(hex_fixed.upper())
other_private_key = RSA.importKey(b64decode(private_key))
cipher = Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5.new(other_private_key)
decrypt_text = cipher.decrypt(decode_data, None).decode()
print(decrypt_text)
```