# RSA Decryption exception: The length of the data to decrypt is not valid for the size of this key

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes, rsa

I have got an Angular + Net Core application with an (RSA + AES) encrypted connection.
All requests from client are coming via POST. (You will be given an example below.

The script provided below works quite well but throws in 5% cases an exception:

> The length of the data to decrypt is not valid for the size of this key
>   in the line:

```
var decryptedAesKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rsaCng.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(request.k), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1));
```

Encryption part (Front-end)

```
encrypt(requestObj:any):any {  
var rsaEncrypt = new JsEncryptModule.JSEncrypt();
var key = this.generateAesKey(32); //secret key
var iv = this.generateAesKey(16); //16 digit

var stringifiedRequest = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(requestObj));
var aesEncryptedRequest = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(stringifiedRequest, 
CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), 
{ 
  keySize: 128 / 8,
  iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv),
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
 });

rsaEncrypt.setPrivateKey(this.publicPemKey);
var encryptedKey = rsaEncrypt.encrypt(key);
var encryptedIV  = rsaEncrypt.encrypt(iv);

var encryptedRequestObj = {
    k: encryptedKey,
    v: encryptedIV,
    r: aesEncryptedRequest.toString()
 };

return encryptedRequestObj;
```

}

Decryption part (C# Back-end)

```
var decryptedAesKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rsaCng.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(request.k), 
RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1));
var decryptedAesIV = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rsaCng.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(request.v), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1));

byte[] encryptedBytes = request.r;
AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider()
{
    Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
    Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
    Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decryptedAesKey),
    IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decryptedAesIV)
};

ICryptoTransform crypto = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
byte[] secret = crypto.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
crypto.Dispose();

requestJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(secret);
```

***Example***, a user wants to open a page by id.

Front-end:
1) encrypts request Id using **AES**
2) encrypts AES' key & iv using **RSA**
3) sends to Back-end

Back-end:
1) decrypts AES' key & value using **RSA**  <--- BREAKS HERE
2) decrypts request Id using **AES' key & iv**
3) decrypts and get id as if there was no encryption

This logic works quite well but breaks sometimes...

**EXAMPLE OF FAILING request:**

```
{ "k":"L+ikMb/JGvFJmhBpADMGTVLFlkHOe69dZUVSQ5r7yHCvWSwY2x6KMR274ByflF0lDMYdCmywo+Nfq6JUybRctDqmAp8UFHXnhwBAv49d99mF5x2yGbJr/j0cn6EZyhweNK4p97i5yMM6MQtluZTIErpsUa22Cajtj8F+xl0jJPUMXIf8cs2X+ooFr5VP/p/vlbPmnEY3K/hMCRZRdXMkEqaCWoA5EnYMTQABtRXPZWgLSQwJpr4dqEAhGCBtga1AGsKF3dQCsKO92NYyst0ngkBiKwFNfy1QDwbk4SzKAKeBckaY17SHt526NMvpEv08BGV6btBxcM+ypsmpB4o0",
"v":"LIndJOjUgKHDlXqwpg7uSmDuut3oi5z9L/GKm2KgU7P2EXmf/JIpXM0JgpTXPJL7wUTndq3F9UMlMdU70JBOV56x/4uIBRbHbyvaG2JZYxbBZblwyYgdo1ZcK1OSE4k5oesQmMEGNEk9RVu+EZO4xAme6+mlyd2/Y/709jaC90PuiOG/k/4JMTTI/2q4s7tk6IgSxLBT8ZiOtgJVGdasSaAksEBMRHyUkzAIr5tSUw1VXedwJFPfwQT2nOD5dU2cxiNJKOwtO9uAYXly0U0FDoa/nkWskca8zaU+4EiPikJ6Km7phViH9JvwZFgHhBj+8FM6Jof+AdrY3q1dcMLFlg==",
"r":"OJnA3wFoKKG+iu4FciXyJg=="
}
```

**EXAMPLE OF CORRECT REQUEST:**

```
{   "k":"uW8d7vIzlgkEkKTkDnHbBZeqKwdgoG+1BVZ/NUiC0pZ/LqZM9aUasQSx+qDg+X50ur30uRnEyAyIZXruYeHQb8cacx5mvr9LWLud+wueJXsOlEEdocD/4A1DfE9TDFdnTaVcMSIwhSVlLPUjO7ubJdANY9yK4S+vb0IyPbsrYpAT7ho01mDkvsH1rZsId/TmzQadmsGhThowu+mrQlz78rrdlN8nI5LnUQHXRNWMUgBvuteTpVBmyrfnIELIKoo/jI6Nj4rGPQBf7+2OOoZPs0Y1GtjXxUCTAt7madNLKSOdaPjdWjaOfGSwnymDNeEFyJQOmAwHZoOGYNd2B/UhQQ==",
"v":"IimiJFcKv5ZHWHljJixX0LUgV4I2GWAWPbk7dWHVhwmHEhTHA/hCdih/E1wiWFS+0KaL05ZobiZInyK7gCwYPHaz0aRCSQtVeBPiFg4f7L0gwfvk1GHwJ1wZjqNJZaYf0elXJzc2l5BwN+aXNWaNJDPA7M6kfK6UPkq84IV3ohCQcTuC8zPM7aMJHxpz9IudcrMmYIkeqrj9Do88CkTLv8yg5hk3EASPk9HqsUieuQixggv/8ZlHnp00iftc62LJlIuCkGn4WR3FkMdFdqpKXf6Ebj8PU1HOmokEtKtYJiOZ5JxieZO5Pnd+ez6sO7khIbdRFDhAQ20chsxKUypezw==",
"r":"2mbUgU44JFFDlWu8As2RIw=="
}
```

Comment: If you want to transfer the Key with RSA you should use [RSA-KEM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76857/18298).

Comment: Unfortunately, RSA-KEM is not well supported yet in C# + Javascript

Comment: Well, PKCS#1 v1.5 overhead at least 11 bytes. One can still use all possible input space for Input Key Material for HKDF. That is better in terms of key generation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of the failed request, the Base64 decoded encrypted AES key has a length of 255 bytes. For a 2048 bit RSA key it should actually be 256 bytes, as it is for the remaining data.

For the RSA-encryption *JSEncrypt* is used, which has a known bug that sporadically causes too short ciphertexts and which is probably responsible for your issue, see [here](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt/issues/158). This bug was opened in July 2019 and is not fixed yet.

Within *JSEncrypt* the too short ciphertexts are processed correctly, so that no error occurs. Cross platform however, this is often not the case, because the too short ciphertexts are strictly speaking invalid and therefore some programming languages identify them as invalid, e.g. [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57035263/jsencryptjs-encrypt-but-python-cannot-decrypt), apparently C# is another one.

If the too short ciphertext is manually padded from the left to the length of the modulus with `0x00`, the ciphertext should also be decryptable in the C# code.

Update:

- I have *successfully* tested the suggested fix using your code. The ciphertext can be fixed in the JavaScript or C# code. A possible implementation for the JavaScript side is e.g. for the key:

  ```
  encryptedKey = btoa(atob(encryptedKey).padStart(256, "\0"));
  ```

  where `encryptedKey` is the Base64 encoded ciphertext as returned by `JSEncrypt#encrypt`. To ensure that this correction isn't applied to ciphertexts that already have the correct length, a length check is useful: A Base64 encoded ciphertext of length `4 * Math.ceil(256 / 3)` doesn't need to be fixed because it corresponds to a ciphertext of the correct length of 256 bytes, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding).
- You apply the method `setPrivateKey` in the *JSEncrypt* part when setting the public key for the encryption, correct would be `setPublicKey`, see [here](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt#how-to-use-this-library). However, *JSEncrypt* seems to fix this internally, because it works as well. Nevertheless it should be changed, because it's misleading.
- As already mentioned in the comments by @kelalaka, the IV is no secret and doesn't need to be encrypted.

Comment: +1 There is no need to encrypt IV. It can be prepended to ciphertext clearly. +2 one should prefer the RSA-KEM.

Comment: Topaco - do you think if I manually add 0x00 to all breaking encrypted keys, it should solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I would expect that a padding of the raw ciphertext (i.e. the Base64-decoded ciphertext) with 0x00 values to the right length should fix the problem.

Comment: @DenisEvseev - I've successfully tested the suggested fix with your code and described the details in the update section of my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, Topaco - I will give 50 points in 4 hours