# Crypto RSA Encryption randomly generates 255 bytes output instead of 256 in next.js application

Tags: javascript, next.js, encryption, cryptography, rsa

Crypto RSA Encryption randomly generates 255 bytes output instead of expected 256  in next.js application
This results in failure when decrypting the data.

Interestingly this works absolutely fine when using only NodeJS, But randomly gives the issue when run in the browser

Below is my code

```
const publicKey = `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----`;

const rsaEncryption = (incomingData:string): string => {
    const rsaEncryptedData =  crypto?.publicEncrypt(
        {
            key:        publicKey,
            padding:    crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING,
            oaepHash:   "SHA-1"
        },
        Buffer.from(incomingData)
    );

      if(rsaEncryptedData.length < 256) {
        //alert('short payload')
        console.error('xxx rsaEncryptedData length: ', rsaEncryptedData.length)
        console.error('xxx rsaEncryptedData: ', rsaEncryptedData)
        console.error('xxx incomingData: ', incomingData, '\n incomingData length: ', incomingData.length, '\n','\n ====end====')
    } else {
      console.log('success, expected output ', rsaEncryptedData.length)
}

   return { rsaEncryptedData }
}
// End RSA encryption function


///
    const startEncryption =() => {
        const data= 'CF9FNcUpvrzExofwhFKvxameOQoe8iZz'
        let codition = 256;
        while(codition >= 256){
            const receivedData = rsaEncryption(data);
            codition = receivedData.rsaEncryptedData.length;
            if(codition < 256) {
                alert();
                console.error('xxx receivedData:\n ', receivedData.rsaEncryptedData.length, '\n -----end-')
            }
        }
    }

startEncryption()
```

using in nextjs application current node version is v16.20.2

Comment: That would be a bug if true, or at least not compliant with RFC 8017. I notice this line seems wrong: `const receivedData = rsaEncryption(aes);`. I think `aes` should be `data` there.

Comment: Maybe only leading 0x00 are trimmed. A workaround would then be to pad the ciphertext afterwards with leading 0x00 values to the key size (i.e. the size of the modulus). The decryption should then be successful. BTW, in the code, `rsaPublicKey` is not defined, probably you mean `publicKey`.

Comment: @Topaco Agree there are couple of typos there.
appreciate your replies. Could you please share some reference to implement the solution you've suggested

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thanks for pointing out the typo. If you could share some references to fix the issue it'll of great help

Comment: If really only the leading 0x00 bytes are truncated, there is a similar bug as with the JSEncrypt library, which can be fixed e.g. as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60728041/9014097). After the fix, the ciphertext should be decryptable. Otherwise the ciphertext is corrupted in another way.